# Save a TSkSVG that has RotationAngle and Paint it with PaintTo rotated into Canvas

Tags: delphi, skia4delphi

I have a `TSkSVG` image object (From the Skia4Delphi Library) on top of another `TImage` object. The `TSkSVG` image is rotated, and I want to save it combined with the Image in the `TImage` Component.

When I use the `TskSVG.PaintTo` procedure, the SVG Image will be drawn onto the TImage, but lost its rotation angle.

Any suggestions on how to solve that?